# Merge 2 branches in git ignoring branch in between?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-extensions

I want to merge a branch into another branch selectively & then merge another branch ignoring 1 branch in between. How do I do this with Git? I am using Git Extensions for visual studio.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "ignoring one branch in between"?  Do you mean ignoring one commit? You can either merge the commit directly in, or you can cherry-pick it if its not directly after the branch point.

Comment: @Daniel I want to ignore the commit on branch right to 1 (without the circle).

Comment: The "secret" is this: Merge doesn't actually merge in a branch.  It actually merges in a *commit*.  If the commit is a branch-tip, that has the *effect* of merging in a branch.  To merge a specific commit, `git merge commit-ID` (commit-ID is an SHA-1, or branch~N, or whatever) (and you may want to use `--no-commit` so you can tweak the merge message, although you can always just `commit --amend` afterward if you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git you do not really merge branches. You merge two commits by adding a new merge commit. The new merge commit has those two commits as parents and contains the merge result.

If I understand your question correctly you want to merge the two circled commits, which are currently referred to by `Logout_IdleUser` and `Various_Fix`.

In this case you might want to do:

```
git checkout Logout_IdleUser
git merge Various_Fix
```

This would merge both circled commits by creating a merge commit. It will also move `Logout_IdleUser` to point to the new merge commit.

If you want a different result, please describe you intended final situation more precisely.